# PipedInputStream not reading from PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, stream

So I'm trying to move an operation that involved writing and reading to and from the disk into just writing to a piped stream. Here's the old system, which operated on two threads:

Writing:

`AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(name));`

Reading:

`Wave wave = new Wave(new File(name));`

And here's the new system:

Writing:

```
PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
pipedOutputStream.connect(pipedInputStream);

AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, pipedOutputStream);
ReadingThread.queue.add(pipedInputStream);
```

Reading:

```
Wave wave = new Wave(new BufferedInputStream(queue.poll());
```

The old system works properly, and data gets through, but in the new system data does not get to the other end. Wave can be initialised by a file or input stream.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not get to the other end"? Are you sure you are closing the output?

Comment: I've added a call to close but even so it gets stuck on this line when testing:

`AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, pipedOutputStream);`

For some reason or another on the second execution of this line it blocks the thread.

Comment: Once you close a stream you can't use it again, I assume you are creating a new stream each time.

Comment: Yes. Each time the method is called the pipedOutputStream and pipedInputSteam is recreated.

Comment: Just checking, but you are saying it doesn't block the first time, only the second time? And you are sure there is a thread reading the piped stream? (Because if it had thrown an Exception and died, it would block waiting for the reader)

Comment: That's correct. And a new object is created each time so in theory it shouldn't matter. The writer should be able to write the initial data to the pipedOutputStream before it gets read by the other thread.